# A question on bounded operator $\|T_A x\|\leq K\|x\|$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, operator-theory

We consider an operator $T_A:H\rightarrow H$, where $H$ is an Hilbert Space and $A$ is its associated $N\times N$ matrix. $T_A$ is said "bounded" if there exists a constant $K>0$ such that
$$\|T_A x\|\leq K\|x\|$$
for each $x\in H$. From this, can we infer that, if $y\in\mathbb R^N$, $$K_1|y|^2\leq Ay\cdot y\leq K_2 |y|^2?$$
Here $0<K_1<K_2$. I think that the consequence of this kind should be possible because $\|T_A\|\leq K$ but... in what way?

Comment: If such a lower bound is given, $A$ is called positive definite. The inequality is not possible in general. For example, if $-1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $Ay\cdot y = -|y|^2$ is not positive.

Comment: Note that boundedness is always true for finite dimensional Hilbert/normed spaces.

Comment: Thank you! I need to study this subject, which book or website do you recommend?

Comment: Do you want to study only finite dimensional stuff?

Comment: @John, Yes. Books and websites are good either.

Comment: There's an online one here http://linear.ups.edu/download.html, which is free but I am not sure of its quality. I like this one a lot: http://www.amazon.ca/Linear-Algebra-Edition-Stephen-Friedberg/dp/0130084514. However, I am not sure if my suggestion is in any way useful to you. I know nothing your math background anyway.